# Function : system.windows.messagebox

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to put another value than yes no on a message box (system.windows.messagebox) ?
Is it possible not to have the "no".
I would see something like:
"the application will restart, press [yes, ok,**] when ready"

Thks

Comment: Hello

Is it possible to put another value than yes no on a message box (system.windows.messagebox) ? Is it possible not to have the "no". I would see something like: "the application will restart, press [yes, ok,**] when ready"

Thks

Comment: What code are you currently using?

Comment: The flavors of message box buttons you can have with a standard message box are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons).

Comment: Yes thks !! i used "YesNo" and i wanted only "yes or ok " I had not found this link, this one actually helps me a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

The type `[System.Windows.Messagebox]` has multiple overloaded versions of the `show` method, which allow various options to be set.

Here is a simple example using the version of `show` which takes a string representing the message text, a string representing the message title, and a `[System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]` indicating which buttons to place in the message box:

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('This is my message text','Message Title',[System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::Ok)
```

You can review the various types of `System.Windows.MessageBoxButtons` to see what works best for your situation.

Comment: Yes i like to use. ;)

Comment: But how to show this box in current user session if i deploy that by policie ? do you know ? thks

Answer (score 0):

Showing all the overloads:

```
Add-Type -assemblyname PresentationFramework
[Windows.MessageBox]::Show

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
static System.Windows.MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton button, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage icon, System.Windows.MessageBoxResult
defaultResult, System.Windows.MessageBoxOptions options)
static System.Windows.MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton button, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage icon, System.Windows.MessageBoxResult
defaultResult)
static System.Windows.MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton button, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage icon)
static System.Windows.MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton button)
static System.Windows.MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption)
static System.Windows.MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText)
static System.Windows.MessageBoxResult Show(System.Windows.Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton button, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage icon,
System.Windows.MessageBoxResult defaultResult, System.Windows.MessageBoxOptions options)
static System.Windows.MessageBoxResult Show(System.Windows.Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton button, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage icon,
System.Windows.MessageBoxResult defaultResult)
static System.Windows.MessageBoxResult Show(System.Windows.Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton button, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage icon)
static System.Windows.MessageBoxResult Show(System.Windows.Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton button)
static System.Windows.MessageBoxResult Show(System.Windows.Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption)
static System.Windows.MessageBoxResult Show(System.Windows.Window owner, string messageBoxText)
```